# Is there a way to escape any character in python

Tags: python-3.x, escaping

So Im doing a project, where I have to store data in a file manually(must be readable)
Im using the '|' as a delimiter. So obviously, when i encounter a '|' symbol to be inputted into the file, I must make a way of escaping reading that to prevent a wrong read.

But unlike default escape characters, like `\n or \t`, `\|` when stored in a variable automatically changes to `\\|`. I have tried raw strings, using replace function, etc.

But none helpful

```
>>>x = '\|'
>>>x
'\\|'
>>>x = '\t'
>>>x
'\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just being printed that way. If you do `print(r'\|')`, it will print `\|`. Try writing it to a file like this:

```py
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(r'\|')
```

This will put `\|` into the file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, however this was not what i was looking for. I don't use print but instead am just getting the value stored into the variable. Storing it in a file does the same thing of not escaping the character. If i read from the file, the output is still `\\|`.

Comment: Let me rephrase... It's just being *displayed* that way. So that you can easily copy-paste the string. It actually contains just one backslash. Try printing the length of that string. It'll say `2`.